# HTML form losing functions when select function is populated with php code

Tags: php, html, forms, select

My php coding causes other form boxes, selections and buttons to disappear

I have a php form that includes 2 select functions that are populated using php code that selects the data and separates the values that are separated with a comma to populate the options with a line per value excluding the comma's, I have put a visualization below to help show what is happening;

**SQL content for column**

```
Black & Blue,Black & White,Black & Red
```

**Select function on form**

```
Black & Blue
Black & White
Black & Red
```

The code works fine, on its own but when you incorporate it into a form the code causes the other form items to disappear, if you remove the code the other items are visible but if you reintroduce it the form items disappear.

I have placed the problematic code below;

```
<select name="col" id="col">
<option>Select Colour</option>
        <?php
        include "publicaccess.php";
        if ($link->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $stmt = ("SELECT `Colours` FROM `shopprod`");
        foreach ($link->query($stmt) as $row_program){
            $options = $row_program['Colours'];
            $optionsArr = explode(",", $options);   
            foreach ($optionsArr as $row){
                echo '<option>' . $row . '</option>';
        }
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $link->close();
        ?>
</select>
```

I was expecting the 2 select functions to populate and allow the rest of the form to be used but the rest of the form disappears when the php code is in use.

The error that it is bringing up is "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on string"

Any constructive suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: can you check the source-code in your browser when the other form elements disappear? Maybe it's throwing some error. Check if the rest of the HTML is being rendered or not. If not, then try to identify the last line that got executed. Share your results or add the error text to the question if you find any.

Comment: Could you add some more code to include the whole form and maybe also add the generated html?

Comment: Remove `$stmt->close();`  $stmt contains just sql string. Can not call close on this.

Comment: Fixed, thank you #ascsoftw that fixed it. Sometimes it is easy to overlook a simple test or solution when you are so focused on a problems complexity.

Answer (score 0):

the comment by member ascsoftw "Remove $stmt->close(); $stmt contains just sql string. Can not call close on this" has answered the question.